# composition function n times Haskell

Tags: haskell, function-composition

anyone knows how to create a function (addOne'') which do a given function (addOne') n times over itself (addOne')? basically f(f(x)) n times

```
addOne :: Int -> Int
addOne x = x*2

addOne' :: [Int] -> [Int]
addOne' [] = []
addOne' (x:xs) = addOne x : addOne' xs

addOne'' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
addOne'' ????
```

so I want to do function addOne' over itself n times. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: write it recursively. What is `addOne'' 0 list`? And how can you write `addOne'' n list` in terms of `addOne'' (n-1) list`?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what `addOne''` is supposed to do. `addOne'` is not repeating `addOne` a number of times, but mapping `addOne` over a list (`addOne' = map addOne`).

Comment: @chepner I think `addOne'' n` is supposed to compose `addOne'` with itself `n` times.

Comment: Also, a small improvement you can make: `addOne` is just `(+1)`, so `addOne' (x:xs) = (x+1) : addOne' xs`. You shouldn’t need `addOne` as a separate function.

Comment: You probably already know how to recursively compute `x+x+x+x+....` which sums the same `x` N times. Use the same technique to compute `f.f.f.f.f. ....` to self-compose a function N times. Use `(.)` instead of `(+)`, and `id` instead of `0`.

Comment: Hint: `iterate f x = f x : iterate f (f x)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only need simple recursion. If you want to make this function yourself, here is a possible implementation :

```
recN :: (a -> a) -> Int -> (a -> a)
recN f n = recN_ f n
  where recN_ acc 1 = acc
        recN_ acc n_ = recN_ (f . acc) (n_ - 1)


-- usage : x4 is a function the multiply by 4, defined as (*2).(*2)
-- let x4 = recN (*2) 2 in x4 2
-- => 8
```

Notice that this solution uses a recursive subfunction with an accumulator. This is a common pattern in functional programming. Also, this function will run forever (or almost) if called with a negative or null 'n'. You can fix this situation using, for example, pattern guards instead of pattern match for the edge condition of the recursion.

Answer (score 1):

Very short (`n > 0`)

```
reapply :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
reapply n f = foldr1 (.) $ replicate n f
```

---

Alternative (`n >= 0`)

```
reapply' :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
reapply' n f x = (iterate f x) !! n
```

---

Point-free (`n >= 0`)

```
reapply'' :: Int -> (a -> a) -> a -> a
reapply'' n f = flip (!!) n . iterate f
```

Comment: `reapply n f x = foldr ($) x $ replicate n f` forks for `n==0` as well . :)

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is looking for a succinct way to to write `f ^ n`, a function that applies `f` `n` times, here is one:

```
foldr (.) id (replicate n f)
```

For example, `(+1) ^ n = (+n)` is:

```
foldr (.) id (replicate n (+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP's comment below, OP may be interested in the `iterate` function, which repeatedly applies an argument to an initial value to create a list where each element documents the result at a certain step.

```
iterate :: (a -> a) -> a -> [a]
iterate f x =  x : iterate f (f x)
```

If you take the nth element of the resulting list, that will be the result when the function is applied n times.

```
iterate f x !! n == f . f .... f . f $ x
--                  '-- n times ---'
```

Comment: I am trying to make a function (addOne' ') which takes an integer for example 3 and do the function addOne' 3 times as a composition way. This means the result of first operation will be the input of the second operation and result of second operation will be the input of the third and so on. For example addOne' [2,4,7] returns [3,5,8], now I want to do addOne' ' 3 [2,4,7] which will give [5,7,10]. I wish I did a better example this is too simple. Sorry if I am not explaining very well but I guess you get the idea.